# Is $W$ connected or nowhere dense?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let,$W\subset \mathbb R^{n}$ ba a linear subspace of dimension at most $n-1$. Which of the following statement(s) is/are true?
>
> (a) $W$ is  nowhere dense.
>
> (b) $W$ is closed.
>
> (c) $\mathbb R^{n}\setminus W$ is connected.
>
> (d) $\mathbb R^{n}\setminus W$ is disconnected.

***My Attempt:***

Suppose that, $n=2$. Then $W\subset \mathbb R^{2}$. Further suppose that $W=\mathbb R$. Then $\mathbb R^{n}\setminus W$ is disconnected.

So, option (c) is false & option (d) is true.

Again, $Int(\bar W)=Int(W)=W\not =\phi $. So, $W$ is **NOT** nowhere dense.

So, option (a) is false.

I have no idea about option (b).

Check my arguments & help about option (b).

Comment: (a) is true. (b) is true.  (c) and (d) depend on which subspace, so they're both false as general statements.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you the response but you should try to find the proofs, as they are not difficult at all.

1. In fact $W$ is nowhere dense (think about a neighborhood in $ℝ^n$ of a point of $W$, so what's the interior of $W$?)
2. Of course $W$ is closed, it's a subspace (prove it)
3. (and 4.) It depends on the dimension, if it's exactly $n-1$ then the complement is disconnected (think about a plane in $ℝ^3$), otherwise it is connected.

Comment: About option (a) where my mistake?@rewritten

Comment: The interior of a subset is made of those points where all a neighborhood of a point is inside the subset. The interior of a plane in 3d space is empty because every point of the plane has a ball around it in space (just to visualize the general idea)

Comment: Maybe you have in mind that W is has interior part "in itself". But every topological space is open in its own topology, by definition. Not as a subset of another space.

Answer (score 0):

rewritten is right. Here are some tips to make this more rigorous:

First for the n-1 case.

Write $W=\mathrm{span}\{e_1,\ldots,e_{n-1}\}$. 
This can be extended to a basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Define $f(a_1e_1 + \cdots + a_ne_n)=a_n$. You can check that $f$ is linear and continuous.

(a) Might be easiest to show the complement is open and dense. For open, see (b) first. For dense, any $a_1e_1+\cdots+a_{n-1}e_{n-1} + 0e_n$ can be approached from $W^C$ by keeping the $a_i$ the same except replacing $a_n$ by a sequence approaching 0.

(b) $W=f^{-1}(\{0\})$. Since $\{0\}$ is closed, $W$ is closed.

(c and d) Let $A=f^{(-1)}(\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x>0\}$ and $B=f^{(-1)}(\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x<0\}$. Then $A$ and $B$ are open and their union is $W^C$.

If the dimension of $W$ is less than $n-1$ then

(b) $W$ is the intersection of a number of $n-1$ dimensional subspaces.

(a) Same as above

(c and d) If its path connected then its connected. So construct a path. You have at least two dimensions to work with. For instance, you could paste three paths together to move to the opposite side of $W$: one going along $e_{n}$, another along $e_{n-1}$, and the last in the opposite direction from the first path along $e_{n}$.